# How to disable fstream on boot

Tags: boot, system

I have a laptop with Elementary OS 0.5 with SSD drive. Every time it boots it executes fstream. Can anybody point me which service needs to be disabled to prevent this. I want to conserve as much battery as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the silence let me respond to myself. To disable fstrim execute this:

```
sudo systemctl stop fstrim.timer
sudo systemctl disable fstrim.timer
sudo systemctl stop fstrim.service
sudo systemctl disable fstrim.service
```